# unable to create docx file from JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am passing a JSON from index.js file to another js file where i am using "easy-template-x" node lib to convert.

When i am trying to do it in same file means passing JSON data in the same JS file , i am able to generate the file successfully with the data.

But when i am trying to pass from another file (bascially getting it from API call from salesforce) , the file is getting generated but there is no data in it.

index.js

```
import jsforce from 'jsforce';
import { test } from './connectdb.js';
var channel = "/event/Account__e";
var user = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var pass = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
var securityToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var replayId = -2; // -1 = Only New messages | -2 = All Window and New 
var conn = new jsforce.Connection();

conn.login(user, pass + securityToken, function (err, res) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }

    var client = conn.streaming.createClient([
        new jsforce.StreamingExtension.Replay(channel, replayId),
        new jsforce.StreamingExtension.AuthFailure(
            function () {
                return process.exit(1);
            }
        )
    ]);
    const dataEvent = '{"Beers": [ { "Brand": "Carlsberg", "Price": 1 },{ "Brand": "Leaf Blonde", "Price": 2 },{ "Brand": "Weihenstephan", "Price": 1.5 }]}'
    test(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataEvent))));
});
```

connectdb.js

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { TemplateHandler } from 'easy-template-x';

// 1. read template file
const templateFile = fs.readFileSync('./template.docx');
  

const test = async (data) => {
    console.log('convert ' + JSON.parse(data))
    const handler = new TemplateHandler();
    const doc = await handler.process(templateFile, JSON.parse(data));

    // 3. save output
    fs.writeFileSync('./myTemplate - output.docx', doc);
}
export { test }
```

Template file

[image]

Comment: What is the point in doing stringify + parse + stringify + (in `test`) parse ? It's only confusing and won't do anything at the end...

Comment: thts my mistake

Comment: I feel like it would work if you'd remove the `' '` around your object so it's an actual object and not a string. Or `JSON.parse` it in case you get it from the API in this way. (not stringify, parse! It's already a string.)